# certificate enrollment via web && without installation

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2008, certificate-authority

Certificate Enrollment API and Cryptography API provided by Microsoft enables us to programmatically apply a certificate and install it on local machine.

After referring to the sample code (enrollWithICertRequest3) which comes with the windows SDK 7.0,  I found that it is possible to apply for a certificate via web service with ICertRequest3 interface. It is cool, but the side effect is that the certificate we applied for has to be installed on the local machine before we can call the createPFX method to extract the final certificate file (with a private key inclueded).

After digging into the ICertRequest3 interface I found the GetCertificate method. But what I can get from this method is a certificate surrounded with "----begin cert---    ---end cert---", which does not contain the private key infomation in it.

I do not know if I have made myself clear enough here. So what I do need is to apply for a certificate via web programmatically but without having to install it on local machine.  The final pxf file is the key point :(

Below is the sample code snippet for your information.

```
    //Get full response for installation
    hr = request3_interface->GetFullResponseProperty(
        FR_PROP_FULLRESPONSENOPKCS7,    //[in] LONG PropId (FR_PROP_*)
        0,                              //[in] LONG PropIndex
        PROPTYPE_BINARY,                //[in] LONG PropType (PROPTYPE_*
        CR_OUT_BASE64,                  //[in] LONG Flags (CR_OUT_*)
        &var_fullresponse);             //[out, retval] VARIANT *pvarPropertyValue
    if(FAILED(hr))
        goto error;

    //Install the response
    hr = enroll2_interface->InstallResponse2(
        AllowNone,                  //[in] InstallResponseRestrictionFlags Restrictions
        var_fullresponse.bstrVal,   //[in] BSTR strResponse
        XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,    //[in] EnrodingType Encoding
        bstr_policyserver_password, //[in] BSTR strPassword
        bstr_policyserver_url,      //[in] BSTR strEnrollmentPolicyServerUrl
        bstr_policyserver_id,           //[in] BSTR strEnrollmentPolicyServerID
        PsfNone,                    //[in] PolicyServerUrlFlags EnrollmentPolicyServerFlags
        policy_server_authtype);        //[in] X509EnrollmentAuthFlags authFlags
    if(FAILED(hr))
        goto error;

    hr = enroll2_interface->CreatePFX(pwd, PFXExportEEOnly, XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, &cert_raw);
    if(FAILED(hr))
        goto error;
```

Any kind of advice will be appreciated. Looking forward for your reply.

Yours,

Jordan

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?